# Rails 4 not raising exception when callbacks fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I get all the other active record error but when there is a callback failure, it goes on and saves the record while actions to be performed in callbacks have malfunctioned.

I am looking for a better way to debug this. A simple configuration would also help. If I can force exceptions to raise instead of being ignored in callbacks.

Comment: What kind of a callback is it? after_save? If it's a before_save or something of that nature, ensure that the callback is returning false in case of failure.

Comment: I have all different kinds, like : after create and after commit etc.. and some models distributes logic depending on the type of callback and sometimes even multiple callbacks run at the same time.

Comment: I see. The point is to verify that the callbacks you're referring to are executed before the object is actually saved. Otherwise, even if the callback fails and returns false, it can't halt the object's being saved, obviously. I think that you should expand your post by pasting some actual code that is malfunctioning in your opinion.

Comment: If you want exceptions, say `save!`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using active scaffold so I dont really have control on what is called for save... but i have complete control of models and all the other files.

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah all i want is to raise a nil exception and tell me the line number in a file. If I am to paste the code I will be pasting entire company's business logic so not possible. sorry

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make any sense to me. If there's a problem then validations should be failing, if validations are failing then models shouldn't get saved. Wouldn't a callback failure result in an invalid model? Maybe you need to provide an example of the sort of problem you're having, pasting a whole class in isn't going to help but a simplified example might.

Comment: @muistooshort that is a good point..  will check it out.. so I am assuming it is not possible in rails to raise exceptions by default on callbacks, i thought since there is a setting like for enabling erros in production, maybe there is something for this as well..

Comment: I still don't know quite what you're trying to do because you refuse to provide the necessary clarification Some callbacks pay attention to return values, some don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67069/discussion-between-whizcreed-and-mu-is-too-short).